# How to make two permission menu with 2 role login in Vue JS 3

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs3

My router file checking what role is logged in:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAdmin)) {
        if(VueJwtDecode.decode(localStorage.getItem('accessToken')).sub == "admin"){
            next()
            return
        }
        next('/auth/login')
    }else if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresStaff)) {
        if(VueJwtDecode.decode(localStorage.getItem('accessToken')).sub == "staff"){
            next()
            return
        }
        next('/auth/login')
    }else {
        next()
    }
})
```

and my admin router is:

```
const adminRoutes = [
    {
        path: '/dashboard',
        name: 'admin.dashboard.index',
        component: () => import( /* webpackChunkName: "admin.dashboard.index" */ '@/views/administrator/dashboard/Index.vue'),
        meta: { requiresAdmin: true, requiresStaff: true, layout: 'default' }, /* Look At this Line */
    },
    // Article Route
    {
        path: '/article',
        name: 'admin.article.index',
        component: () => import( /* webpackChunkName: "admin.article.index" */ '@/views/administrator/article/Index.vue'),
        meta: { requiresAdmin: true, layout: 'default' },
    },
]
```

I have already add `requiresAdmin: true, requiresStaff: true`, in meta field. But when i login with admin, its work. But when i login with staff account, i cant reach dashboard page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you are logged in as staff and you access the dashboard page, this condition is still true: `if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAdmin))`. But as you have the permission `staff` you get redirected to the login page.

A solution would be to define the allowed roles per page explicitly.

```
const adminRoutes = [
    {
        path: '/dashboard',
        name: 'admin.dashboard.index',
        component: () => import( /* webpackChunkName: "admin.dashboard.index" */ '@/views/administrator/dashboard/Index.vue'),
        meta: { roles: ['admin', 'staff'], layout: 'default' },
    },
    // Article Route
    {
        path: '/article',
        name: 'admin.article.index',
        component: () => import( /* webpackChunkName: "admin.article.index" */ '@/views/administrator/article/Index.vue'),
        meta: { roles: ['admin'], layout: 'default' },
    },
]
```

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    const currentRole = VueJwtDecode.decode(localStorage.getItem('accessToken')).sub
    const hasPublicAccess = !record.meta.roles || record.meta.roles.length === 0

    if (hasPublicAccess || to.matched.some(record => record.meta.roles.includes(currentRole)) {
        next()
        return
    }

    next('/auth/login')
    return
})
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try can try with one role for both:

```
else if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAdminStaff)) {
    if(VueJwtDecode.decode(localStorage.getItem('accessToken')).sub == "staff" || 
       VueJwtDecode.decode(localStorage.getItem('accessToken')).sub == "admin"){
        next()
        return
    }
    next('/auth/login')
```

then in admin routes :

```
{
    path: '/dashboard',
    name: 'admin.dashboard.index',
    component: () => import( /* webpackChunkName: "admin.dashboard.index" */ '@/views/administrator/dashboard/Index.vue'),
    meta: { requiresAdminStuff: true, layout: 'default' }, /* Look At this Line */
},
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your help